# How a write a method that iterates through a text file and adds all elements to an arrayList using the Object's equals method

Tags: java, arraylist, while-loop, text-files, equals

I am trying to create Line objects and add them to an array list. The problem I am having is excluding any lines that are similar to each other. I have already created an equals method that compares two lines to determine if they are equal. I am having trouble using the while loop. I do not have an error message. It compiles just fine. It just will not read from the text file. I am stuck and do not know where else to go from here.

```
public void read( File fileName ) throws Exception
{
    reader = new Scanner(fileName);


    //---------------------
    //Have to read the first number before starting the loop
    int numLines = reader.nextInt();
    lines = new ArrayList <Line> (numLines);

    //This loop adds a new Line object to the lines array for every line in the file read.
    while( reader.hasNext() ) {
        for( int i = 0; i < numLines; i++ ) {
            int x = reader.nextInt();
            int y = reader.nextInt();
            Point beg = new Point(x,y);
            x = reader.nextInt();
            y = reader.nextInt();
            Point end = new Point(x,y);

            String color = reader.next();

              Line l =  new Line( beg, end, color );

              if (l.equals(lines.get(i)))
                  break;
              else
                  lines.add(i, l);


        }
    }

    //Print the action to the console
    System.out.println( "reading text file: " + fileName );
    reader.close();

}
```

Comment: "The method lines(int) is undefined for the type MyDrawing
    Void methods cannot return a value" The Errormessage sais it all. You need to use `lines.get(i)`

Answer (score 2):

`lines` is an ArrayList. You cannot access an element `i` of an ArrayList by going `lines(i)` as you do in the code; you need to do `lines.get(i)`.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is clear, you can't return anything in a void function.
So simply modify your code to:

```
  Line l =  new Line( beg, end, color );
  //if not equals, add it
  if (!this.lines(i).equals(lines.get(i))){
            //TODO: add to you collection
  }
```

I hope it helps

Comment: There is no `lines(i)`.

Answer (score 0):

the first exception is already explained by others so I'll explain the other one:

`Void methods cannot return a value`

You created the following method:

```
public void read( File fileName ) throws Exception
```

in your `while` loop you do this:

```
    if (this.lines(i).equals(lines(i)))
        return null;
    else
        lines.add(i, l);
```

You return `null`, while you can use return in a `while` loop, you cannot do it if you declare your method `void`. You should use `break` instead.

Comment: Do you get an error? Or just now output? Try some debugging first, maybe you can see where the error is yourself

Comment: It compiles just fine. It does not run at all.

Comment: It compiles fine but does not run?? So does it give an exception?

Comment: it runs now. It just does nothing.

Comment: Oke try debugging your project, see if it runs through your loops and your if/else

Answer (score 0):

You should not "return null" on a method which has no return value (void). You can just use "return" instead. However I assume what you want is "continue" in stead. Also consider using HashSet in stead of an arraylist, then you don't need to check for equality anymore since the hashset does not allow duplicates.